# Our forebears gathered in forests or the forests?

Tags: articles

The sentence is:

> Our forebears gathered in **forests** and hunted on **the savannas**.

I was wondering can we use the article "the" before the word "forests" or alternatively, avoid using it before the word "savannas"? In the other words, are these sentences correct and natural?

> Our forebears gathered in **the forests** and hunted on **the savannas**.
>
> Our forebears gathered in **forests** and hunted on **savannas**.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify which forests you have in mind, ***the* forests** in this example is not correct.
When you refer to a class of things / objects, you cannot use the definite article.

Thus:

**Forests** are mysterious places (=All forests are mysterious).

***The*** forests in my country are mysterious.

The same applies to *savannas*.

Comment: In other words, this sentence would be correct:  "Our forebears gathered in the forests of North America and hunted on the savannas of Africa."  (In this sentence you are specifying which forests and savannas.)

Comment: @rhetorician Your point being?

Comment: I'm simply following up on the rule contained in the second sentence of your answer by providing the OP with an example that illustrates that rule.  In other words, my exemplar was a pedagogical tool by which I illustrated the rule you laid down.  No offense was intended, and I hope no offense was taken.